Vite React app not serving refresh routes on Azure Web App with nginx
I have read and believe implemented correctly the thread at React-router and nginx however the issue persists.
I have deployed the below to Azure Web App (terraform code provided) and whilst navigating inside the app (clicking links, etc) they successfully route to the various pages.
However when on those pages, ex /signin and I refresh the page then it shows 404 nginx error. Everything works fine locally.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.
main.tf
...
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp-dev-frontend" {
  name                = "wa-dev-visitoranalytics-frontend"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dev.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplandev.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplandev.id

  # Depends on the backend
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_linux_web_app.webapp-dev
  ]

  site_config {
    app_command_line = "/home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh"
  }
}


startup.sh
nginx -g 'daemon off;' -c /home/site/wwwroot/nginx.conf

nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;
error_log /home/LogFiles/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    types {
        text/html                             html htm shtml;
        text/css                              css;
        application/javascript                js;
        application/json                      json;
        image/png                             png;
        image/svg+xml                         svg;
    }

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        root /home/site/wwwroot;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            root /home/site/wwwroot;
            index index.html;

            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /index.html;

        location = /index.html {
            internal;
        }
    }
}

RoutedApp.jsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import SignIn from './components/sign-in/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/sign-up/SignUp';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import { DashboardProvider } from './contexts/DashboardContext';

const RoutedApp = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={
          <PrivateRoute>
            <DashboardProvider>
              <Dashboard />
            </DashboardProvider>
          </PrivateRoute>
        } />
        <Route path="*" element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default RoutedApp;

PrivateRoute.jsx
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { authToken, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return authToken ? children : <Navigate to="/signin" />;
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default PrivateRoute;

vite.config.json
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});

deploy.yml
name: Build & deploy to my-web-app

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  NODE_ENV: staging
  VITE_BUILD_MODE: staging

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: yarn install
        run: |
          yarn install

      - name: Build for ${{ env.VITE_BUILD_MODE }}
        run: |
          yarn vite build --mode ${{ env.VITE_BUILD_MODE }}

      - name: yarn run test
        run: |
          yarn run test

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: dist

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Dev Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Dev Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: my-web-app
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_DEV }}
          package: .

